# Copying worksheet from personal workbook to active workbook (with macro in personal macro workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a worksheet from my personal workbook to my active workbook, with a macro (saved in personal macro workbook).

The problem in the code below is here: Workbooks("excel1.xlsx"). In my case the file name is non-constant. But the constant is this: I always have 2 workbooks open, the personal workbook and this  non-constant workbook. And I work in the latter one.

Is it possible to alter the above, so that I don't need the file name? Maybe if I refer to it as the always open workbook instead?

```
Sub Macro1()

Windows("PERSONAL.XLSB").Activate
Sheets("Attributes").Select
Sheets("Attributes").Copy After:=Workbooks("excel1.xlsx").Sheets(1)

End sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Attributes").Copy After:=activeworkbook.Sheets(1)` should do it.

Comment: If I replace "Workbooks("excel1.xlsx")" with "ActiveWorkbook", it copy the worksheet to the personal workbook and not to the other workbook, which I want.

Comment: Don't activate Personal.xlsb (which should really be hidden) first.

Comment: If you use `ActiveWorkbook`, you need to remove the other two lines. Doing `Activate` and `Select` will mess up the user-chosen `ActiveWorkbook`. Instead, you should add the workbook to the copy line like `Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Sheets("Attributes").Copy ...`

Comment: PERSONAL.XLSB is most likely my ActiveWorkbook. How can I make my other workbook (let's say excel1.xlsx) my active workbook without using its filename?

Comment: Thank you so much. With Toddleson's last comment I (we) made it! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Worksheet to Another Workbook

- It will loop through all open workbooks and copy the worksheet to the first workbook that is not hidden (credits to Rory in the comments) and isn't the source workbook (`PERSONAL.xlsb`).
- It doesn't matter which workbook is active.
- Here are some undesired scenarios covered in the code:

  - the worksheet doesn't exist in the source,
  - there is no destination workbook (only the source workbook is open),
  - the worksheet already exists in the destination workbook.
- The error-handling routine will cover possible other undesired scenarios.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertAttributesWorksheet()
    Const ProcName As String = "InsertAttributesWorksheet"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const wsName As String = "Attributes"
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Check if the worksheet exists in the source workbook.
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sws = swb.Worksheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    If sws Is Nothing Then ' doesn't exist in source
        MsgBox "The worksheet '" & wsName & "' doesn't exist " _
            & "in the source workbook '" & swb.Name & "'.", _
            vbCritical, ProcName
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' exists in source
    End If
    
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = swb.Name
    
    ' (the first workbook that is not hidden and is not the source workbook)
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    
    For Each dwb In Workbooks
        If Windows(dwb.Name).Visible = True Then ' is not a hidden workbook
            If dwb.Name <> swbName Then ' is not the source workbook
                ' Check if the worksheet exists in the destination workbook.
                Dim dws As Worksheet
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(wsName)
                On Error GoTo ClearError
                If dws Is Nothing Then ' doesn't exist in destination
                    sws.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(1)
                    MsgBox "The worksheet '" & wsName & "' was added " _
                        & "to the workbook '" & dwb.Name & "'.", _
                        vbInformation, ProcName
                    Exit Sub
                Else ' already exists in destination
                    MsgBox "The worksheet '" & wsName & "' already exists " _
                        & "in the destination workbook '" & dwb.Name & "'.", _
                        vbCritical, ProcName
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            'Else ' is the source workbook
            End If
        'Else ' is a hidden workbook
        End If
    Next dwb

    MsgBox "No other workbook found.", vbExclamation, ProcName

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```